# PHP PhantomJS not loading in class through Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, mamp

I've followed the [installation guide](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/installation.html) for **PHP PhantomJS**. When running a test script using PHP PhantomJS, I'm getting the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found in ...`

I haven't used Composer before, so I maybe overlooking something. I'm running this from MAMP, so there may be some specifics to do with that that are not mentioned in the documentation. If I open the test script in a browser I get a blank screen. It's only from running the php from Terminal that I get the `Fatal error`.

The line the script fails on is:

```
$client = Client::getInstance();
```

I therefore presume that it is not loading properly from Composer. I can verify that in `/bin` are both `phantomjs` and `phantomloader`.

What steps should I take to get the PHP PhantomJS script loaded correctly?

--update--

**test.php** (taken directly from PHP PhantomJS example)

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('http://google.com');

$client->send($request, $response);

if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```

Comment: what test script do you mean? are you sure the composer autoload script is loaded in this test script?

Comment: Have updated the question. I presumed the `use` command handles the autoloading, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to include the composer autoloader in your script if you dont use one yourself.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This is an autogenerated autoload script by composer.
See here https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

I'm afraid the *Use* statement will not take care of the autoloading, it will just define the namespace to look in for the *Client* class.

Comment: But in my case it is not working no output form above script.